# How to stop propagation of mouse and all events to parent but allow events to the components and its children

Tags: c++, qt, qml, mouseevent, qquickwidget

```
class PageGroupHandler: public QQuickWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PageGroupHandler();
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
};

PageGroupHandler::PageGroupHandler()
    : QQuickWidget(QUrl("qrc:/custom/qml/PagesGroups/PageManager.qml"))
{
    this->installEventFilter(this);
}
bool PageGroupHandler::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == this || obj->parent() == this) {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

NOTE: There is no error. I have loaded a qml component, it has some rectangle components, some have mouse event some does not, so when i scroll on it the events works but when there is no scroll area the parent which itself is an scrollarea starts scrolling, its pretty weird.

Comment: It is really unclear from this what it is you want to accomplish. Please provide a [mre] and a better description of what you would like to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: It's also completely pointless to install an event filter on the same object. Just override `event()`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply @musicamante, @JarMan. I removed event filter trying to override the event but nothing work. In some approach parent still gets the unwanted mouse event, in some qml doesnt load at all. `      bool event(QEvent *event) override {
        event->setAccepted(true);
        event->accept();
        return true;
    }  ` here qml doesnt load

Comment: @MohammadImran The above notes are still valid, and **nobody** can help you unless you provide a proper MRE and a better description of your case. Please take your time to properly follow the [tour], read [ask] and then [edit] your question accordingly, otherwise it will be closed as insufficient details have been provided.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand when you move mouse, you get that event on most child widget first. So you can just override specific event (e.g. CustomWidget::mouseMoveEvent...) in child widget and NOT call parent implementation (e.g. QWidget::mouseMoveEvent) and parent widget does not receive that event.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your kind suggestions, answers and helpful informations.
I guess i am not very good at asking questions, but since i have solved the problem, i would to like to answer my question.

Ques: QQuickwidget loads QML component with scrollarea. How to stop unwanted mouse event propagation to qquickwidget parent(QWidget) but allow loaded QML to respond to mouse events.

```
class PageGroupHandler: public QQuickWidget     
{
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    { 
        return obj == root ? true: QQuickWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);/*step 1*/
    }
};
PageGroupHandler::PageGroupHandler()
    : QQuickWidget(QUrl("qrc:/custom/qml/PagesGroups/PageManager.qml"))
{
    root = rootObject(); /*loaded qml*/
    rootContext()->setContextProperty("pageGroupWindow", this);
    pageGroupSizeType = PageGroupSizeType::Full;
    setSizeZero();

    root->installEventFilter(this); /*step 2*/
};
```